# How to evaluate a mathematical expression stored as string in SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

There  is a table TAB1 with column COL1 as varchar, which stores simple mathematical expression. I want to evaluate this expression

eg.TAB1--

### COL1(varchar(50)

2+4+4

1+1

2+9

---

Output should be -

### COL1_val(integer)

10

2

11

---

I have tried select cast(col1 as integer) from tab1, but doesn't work.

Comment: Is Netezza the type of SQL engine you are using?  In general, your table design is not good because it us unnormalized.

Comment: It is how the data is coming and we have to evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server , dynamic sql is used.

```
declare @sql varchar(100)
set @sql = 'select ' + ' 2+3+4'

exec(@sql)

--Output 9
```

Comment: this will work only for 1 row. It should work for all rows. Anad we cannot use a custom function